# como funciona o Zconnectongroup?

Tags: delphi, zeos

Alguem ja usou o zconnectiongroup?
tenho que importar diversos arquivos cvs para o banco de dados FB,
ai pensei em importar em diversas conexões, para ser mais rápido(ja que cada conexao usaria um core).

vi esse zconnectiongroup, e pelo que entendi com ele daria para abrir diversas conexoes com ele, mas não entendi como configura-lo e usa-lo.